# Transforming <svg> element in SVG behaves differently in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: svg

I have a fairly simple SVG which I've converted into a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Here's the SVG (and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xy26f8n4/) you can see for yourself):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <rect id="leader" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" fill="none" />

  <svg id="left" x="5%" y="5%" width="40%" height="85%">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="left" x="55%" y="5%" width="40%" height="85%" transform="scale(.5)">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

I'm expecting a large, empty red rectangle containing two smaller rectangles: one blue one which takes up quite a bit of space and another one (red) which is half the size of the blue one. There is a translation which occurs as well, but that's not terribly important for this question.

In Firefox, I get the expected image, which is this:

[image: SVG in Firefox]

However, when I view the same image in Chrome (or Safari), it seems to be ignoring my transformation, and the two rectangles are both the same size:

[image: SVG in Chrome/Safari]

Is there something wrong with my SVG, is this a bug in either of these browsers, or is this an unsupported part of SVG in Chrome/Safari? There is an [old bug from early 2017](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=701075) which is reported to be fixed, so I'm thinking that I'm missing something about the way SVG transforms are supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transform` attribute for an `<svg>` element has only been introduced for [SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#SVGElement). For now it is not supported in all browsers. (Setting a `version` attribute on the root element has no effect.)

You can achieve the same effect if you wrap the `<svg>` element with a `<g>` and define the transformation there. The percentage values for the positioning will still be relative to the nearest parent element establishing a viewport, which is the outer `<svg>`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect id="leader" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" fill="none" />

  <svg id="left" x="5%" y="5%" width="40%" height="85%">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>

  <g transform="scale(.5)">
    <svg id="left" x="55%" y="5%" width="40%" height="85%">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The bug you referenced, btw, does not apply. It's not easy to see at first glance, but the attached [test case](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/attachmentText?aid=275057) shows this refers to setting a transformation on a `<g>` element via script.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation *and* the workaround. Works great across the browsers I cared to try :)